# How to add artifacts from a submodule build directory?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have the following project structure:

```
project-root
    |
    |__lib
    |   |
    |   |__target
    |   |    |____lib.jar
    |   |    |____lib.so
    |   |___src
    |   |    |____ ...
    |   |
    |   |_pom.xml
    |
    |___model
    |     |
    |     |_pom.xml
    |     |
    |    ...
    |
    |__pom.xml
```

So I have 2-modules project: `lib` and `model` where model produces the `tar.gz` distribution using `maven-assembly-plugin`. The thing is the building of lib causes to produce native library `lib.so` which needs to be copied into the `tar.gz` in order to be used.

How to make `maven-assembly-plugin` to include artifact from one sub-module's build directory into the dirstribution (e.g. `tar.gz` in my case)

Answer (score 0):

In your assembly [descriptor](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) file, You can add lib.so file to your tar package. (I am assuming you already have a descriptor for maven assembly to create tar.gz package)

I am modifying default [jar-with-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) descriptor here for an example.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>custom-descriptor</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>

  <!-- You need to add following to your current descriptor -->
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/../../lib/target</directory>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.so</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet> 
  </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

We need to give relative path to directory section. (I don't know any other way for non published files) OutputDirectory determines in which folder the file will be copied in the created archive. (You can leave it as "/" If you want it in the root of the archive.

When using assembly plugin( You probably have it like this)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
               <!-- descriptor file previously created. -->
               <descriptor>custom-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase> 
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    .....
  </build>
```

In this case custom-descriptor.xml file is next to pom.xml file. If its placed somewhere else, relative path should be given in the descriptor tags.

Ps: This will work if lib is built before model.